# python remove weird apostrophe and other weird characters not in string.punctuation

Tags: python, string, unicode, ascii, punctuation

This is my string:

```
mystring = "How’s it going?"
```

**This is what i did:**

```
import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)

def strip_punctuations(mystring):
    for c in string.punctuation:
        new_string=''.join(ch for ch in mystring if ch not in exclude)
        new_string = chat_string.replace("\xe2\x80\x99","")
        new_string = chat_string.replace("\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0","")
    return chat_string
```

**OUTPUT:**

If i did not include this line `new_string = chat_string.replace("\xe2\x80\x99","")` this will be the output:

```
 'How\xe2\x80\x99s it going'
```

i realized
exclude does not have that weird looking apostrophe in the list:

```
print set(exclude)
set(['!', '#', '"', '%', '$', "'", '&', ')', '(', '+', '*', '-', ',', '/', '.', ';', ':', '=', '<', '?', '>', '@', '[', ']', '\\', '_', '^', '`', '{', '}', '|', '~'])
```

How do i ensure all such characters are taken out instead of manually replacing them in the future?

Comment: Python 2, I assume?

Comment: You should not manipulate utf8 strings as bytes. Decode them first.

Comment: Thanks this solved it! just to to use `unicode(mystrin)` then `re.sub(ur"\p{P}+", "", mystrin)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with long texts like news articles or web scraping, then you can either use "goose" or "NLTK" python libraries. These two are not pre-installed. Here are the links to the libraries. [goose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/goose-extractor/1.0.1), [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)

You can go through the document and learn how to do.

OR

if you don't want to use these libraries, you may want to create your own "exclude" list manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

toReplace = "how's it going?"
regex = re.compile('[!#%$\"&)\'(+*-/.;:=<?>@\[\]_^`\{\}|~"\\\\"]')
newVal = regex.sub('', toReplace)
print(newVal)
```

The regex matches all the characters you've set and it replaces them with empty whitespace.